# Leave work-item state as-is when relating to a check-in, by default

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We're getting more rigorous with our check-in policy with TFS, and are enforcing a policy of relating at least one work-item with every check-in.

One problem is that when you relate a work-item with a check-in, by default Visual Studio sets the item's state to "resolved". This is causing frequent unintentional resolvings of work-items.

Is there any way to control this behavior, so that *by default* Visual Studio does not actually change the item's state when relating it to a work-item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no option available in Visual Studio to set this but you can workaround by doing a registry hack. There is a registry key available to set the default.
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Behavior] 
"ResolveAsDefaultCheckinAction"="False"